# How to "archive" records on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to create an "archive" feature in my Rails 3 application. I'm having trouble hiding child relations in my database when the parent is archived.

My project is set up such that the parent record has an attribute called `archived_on`. If the value is nil, then the record is not archived. How can I structure my query so that the child model so that it hides records with a parent that is archived?

The parent model has a scope:

```
scope :archived, where('archived_on != ?', nil)
```

which works fine for the parent model only.

I'm essentially looking for a way to do a Child.where('bla') that only returns things that are not archived.

Is there a way to do this without having to give each child its own `archived_on` attribute?

Comment: "without having to give each child its own archived_on attribute" - nope, there isn't. Cascade archiving is what you should do.

Comment: Blah, that sucks. Do you know of any resources where I can look up some patterns regarding that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

Create a `models/concern/archivable.rb`

```
module Archivable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :archived, -> { where('archived_at != ?', nil) }
  end
end
```

Then include it in your model classes you want to archive.

Generate a migration for each model, adding an 'archived_at' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
# models/concern/archivable.rb

module Archivable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :archived, -> { where.not(archived_at: nil) }
  end
end
```